# how to add a list to another list while looping?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a list which has object(record) taken from database. I need to add it another list of generic class inside a loop.When ever loop executes the final list contains only the last element.my coding are..

```
List<modelclass> mdlclasslist=new ArrayList();
for(Class_1 a:class1list) {
  Query qr=s.createQuery("from Class_2 where ID= :f and code= :j order by mark desc");
  qr.setParameter("f",id);
  qr.setParameter("j",code);
  List<Class_2> b=new ArrayList();
  b=qr.list();
  for(Class_2 cls:b) {
    modelclass mdl=new modelclass(cls.getID(),cls.getCode(),cls.getMark());
    mdlclasslist.add(mdl);
  }
}
```

mdlclasslist contains same object.It is not adding every object the query takes.please advice.

Comment: are you sure you are getting more than one record in `b=qr.list();`

Comment: Where are you using "a" object of class Class_1 in for(Class_1 a:class1list)...?

Comment: Got it.I have to use a.id and a.code to get a new record..Thank for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Query appears to return the same list over and over again for every Class_1 item because **id and code never change**. I assuming your code should rather look like this:

```
Query qr=s.createQuery("from Class_2 where ID= :f and code= :j order by mark desc");

for( Class_1 a : class1list ) 
{
    qr.setParameter( "f", a.id );
    qr.setParameter( "j", a.code );

    for( Class_2 cls: qr.list() )
    {
        modelclass mdl=new modelclass(cls.getID(),cls.getCode(),cls.getMark());
        mdlclasslist.add(mdl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about debugging and printing out the number of elements in the 2nd list before adding?
Not sure if you want to append the List you retrieve from a DB to the one you initialize beforehand...
However, I would define the 1st List to be of the generic type `Class_1` (BTW: read about [Java naming conventions](http://www.iwombat.com/standards/JavaStyleGuide.html#Class%20and%20Interface%20Names)) and then use `addAll`

```
yourList.addAll(theListFromDB);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

listInstance.addAll(anotherListInstavce) ;

Answer (score 0):

First i would check if my source list, the one populated from DB has more than 1 element. If you are using JDBC, its a very common mistake to not move the result set objects further.

Secondly if you need such collection manipulation utilities i suggest take a look at commons-collections ListUtils class.

Answer (score 0):

All the collections have a simple method to add data of one collection to other.

```
list2.addAll(list1);
```

You can simply use this method...